# How to connect social account to already registered user in SecureSocial, when the user is logged in?

Tags: facebook, scala, twitter, playframework-2.2, securesocial

Well, I have a question regarding connecting multiple social accounts using SecureSocial, not through the login menu, but from inside the App.

What I am trying to do is:

- User Logs In the app using SecureSocial
- After he/she logs in the app, they should be allowed to connect their Facebook/Twitter account, what I am trying to do is let users connect to different social account from a logged in session of the app.

To make it more simple, what I mean do is, provide
`"Connect to Facebook"` OR `"Connect to Twitter"` from inside the app, for logged in users. Is there any such functionality in **SecureSocial**??, they have made it really easier for me to integrate social channels in my app, who has no idea whatsoever about social apps.

`Is there some functionality as such provided by SecureSocial, or will I need to create my own modules`, if I am needed to create my own modules, could you guys **give me some pointers** about how to do so. I googled for this issue but couldn't get any suitable answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is support for linking accounts now. Check the master samples on how to do it. If you start an authentication flow when a user is already logged in SecureSocial will invoke a new method called link in UserService.

Comment: Thank you for ans jorge but, I have been using 2.1.3, is the method available in that version as well??

Comment: No, the feature was added after the 2.1.3 release.